# touchesbegan, touchesmoved, touchesended issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, drag-and-drop

For various reasons, I've moved these methods from a UIView subclass to my viewcontroller. And I finally got it working, except for one thing. Not only am I able to drag the UIImageviews I've programmatically created, but the actual view controllers view is draggable too. Creating this much undesired effect. I guess it's the fact that it's touches anyobject, and the background itself is an object. I'm just not sure how exclude the background. I would think that it would need the "UserInteraction enabled", but I guess not? I only want it to make UIImageViews draggable. Please forgive my noobness. I'm still learning.

I have all the imageviews i'd want "touchable" in an NSMutableDictionary called "letterDictionary". Would it be possible to only have touch apply to what's in the dictionary?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdN1T.jpg

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    movingLetter = [touch view];

    CGPoint pointInside = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    if ([movingLetter pointInside:pointInside withEvent:event]) touchedInside = YES;

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (touchedInside) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];  // get the new touch location
        movingLetter.center = CGPointMake(movingLetter.center.x + newPoint.x - touchPoint.x, movingLetter.center.y + newPoint.y - touchPoint.y);         
        touchPoint = newPoint;      
    }
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (touchedInside) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        movingLetter.center = CGPointMake(movingLetter.center.x + newPoint.x - touchPoint.x, movingLetter.center.y + newPoint.y - touchPoint.y);

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect([movingLetter frame], [placeHolder frame]))
            {
                movingLetter.center = placeHolder.center;
            }

    }   
    touchedInside = NO;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchedInside = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the view that was touched,

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    movingLetter = [touch view];
```

just test to see if it is the class you are looking for (e.g. a `UIImageView`) then return

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (![[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
       return;
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I should have known to do that! Out of curiosity though, could you or someone tell me how I would have it add touches to only the objects (UIImageViews) in my NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

In this touchesBegen Method :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet* )touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];

     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    _previousPoint1 = [touch      previousLocationInView:self.main_uiview];
    _previousPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:self.main_uiview];
    _currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.main_uiview];

    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    self.bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [self.bezierPath moveToPoint:_currentPoint];
     }
```

TouchesMove Method

```
  -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent* )event
   {


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    _previousPoint2 = _previousPoint1;
    _previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self.main_uiview];
    _currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.main_uiview];

    lastPoint = _currentPoint;

    [_bezierPath addLineToPoint:lastPoint];

    // calculate mid point
    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint4(_previousPoint1, _previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint4(_currentPoint, _previousPoint1);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bg_imageview.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,brush);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context,kCGLineJoinRound);

    [self.bg_imageview.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bg_imageview.frame.size.width, self.bg_imageview.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);

    // Use QuadCurve is the key
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, _previousPoint1.x, _previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);


    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    self.bg_imageview.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();}
```